# What will be the remainder if $7^{101}$ mod $5$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

$$7^{101} \mod 5 = 49^{100} \mod 5 = (49^2)^{50} \mod 5$$

What is the next step to find solution?

Regards

Comment: $\large \bmod 5\!:\ 7\equiv 2,\ \ \color{#c00}{2^4\equiv 1}\,\Rightarrow\, 2^{4n}\equiv (\color{#c00}{2^4})^n\equiv \color{#c00}1^n\equiv 1\ \ $

Comment: How did you get from $7^{101}$ to $49^{100}$?

Comment: You are wrong in saying $7^{101}\equiv 49^{100}$ you need $7\cdot 49^{50}$ - just take care when manipulating the powers.

Comment: Not every tag which starts with the letters "mod" is about modular arithmetic. I'm surprised you didn't add (modular-forms) in addition to (modules) and (model-theory)!

Comment: This is also [a duplicate of a mother thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/81228/11619) where the techniques for answering questions of this type have been collected. Shame on experienced users who choose to indulge in on-site-plagiarism.

Answer (score 2):

There is something wrong in your first step, indeed

$$7^{101} \not \equiv 49^{100} \mod 5 \ldots $$

More simply use that

$$7^2 \equiv 49 \equiv -1 \pmod 5$$

therefore

$$7^{101} \equiv 7\cdot7^{100} \equiv 7\cdot (7^{2})^{50} \equiv \,? \pmod 5$$

Answer (score 0):

By Carmichael function if $(a,m)=1$, then $a^{k \lambda (M)}\equiv 1 (mod  m)$. That $\lambda (5)=4$. So $7^{4k}\equiv 1 (mod 5)$.

$7^{100}\equiv 1 (mod 5)$ then $7^{101}\equiv 2 (mod 5)$.

Comment: use `\pmod{5}` to render modulo.

Answer (score -1):

What if you do not see a cute way to do this?
There is a more systematic way to do it.
First, $7^x\pmod 5$ is periodic in $x$.  Compute a few of them until you see what the pattern is.  Then it should be easy to find $7^{101}\pmod 5$.